# URL for sending back JSON response when Alexa skill is hosted as a web service

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have a skill (currently in development phase) hosted in AWS. I want to move it to a local machine instead of using lambda function.  I have written an API, exposed it with ngrok publicly and configured it as an endpoint to the skill. I am able to receive the request JSON object from the Alexa skill. But I am not sure to which URL or API do I send the response JSON to.

I have received an `apiEndpoint` and `apiAccessToken` in the request JSON. I have tried sending the JSON to the `apiEndpoint` but I got a 404 (I was expecting this as the URL did not have any skill specific ID but just gave a try). What all do I send in the JSON object and to which URL do I send it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send the response back to the request you receive. Whenever you receive an API request you are supposed to respond back or acknowledge it. In Alexa, you will receive a `POST` request to your endpoint with a payload and you have to return a response in the expected format.

`apiEndpoint` and `apiAccessToken` is used to fetch additional information like device address and pincode.